# Is it possible to match numerical operations done in c and python down to machine precision levels?

Tags: python, c, precision

I want to match the results of a rolling moving average between C and Python down to machine precision levels. Is this a fool's errand?

The original code in C (from talib's [[1](https://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/)] finance library: https://pastebin.com/WuMWBFtF)

The code snippet below is a trivial loop for my own simple moving average and I also threw in a pandas rolling average for good measure.

Outputs (the third column is the errors, with the regularity that screams "machine precision" I guess):

```
                                 talib                                mine                              errors
0                                  nan                                 nan                                 nan
1                                  nan                                 nan                                 nan
2                                  nan                                 nan                                 nan
3                                  nan                                 nan                                 nan
4                                  nan                                 nan                                 nan
5                                  nan                                 nan                                 nan
6                                  nan                                 nan                                 nan
7                                  nan                                 nan                                 nan
8                                  nan                                 nan                                 nan
9                                  nan                                 nan                                 nan
10                                 nan                                 nan                                 nan
11  0.15516036417806491898296883391595  0.15516036417806497449412006517377 -0.00000000000000005551115123125783
12  0.05205880767301387240797438948903  0.05205880767301387240797438948903  0.00000000000000000000000000000000
13 -0.11350055963883017018378751572527 -0.11350055963883017018378751572527  0.00000000000000000000000000000000
14 -0.15543593887235351846953790300176 -0.15543593887235351846953790300176  0.00000000000000000000000000000000
15 -0.01614653775592672646510550293897 -0.01614653775592670911787074317090 -0.00000000000000001734723475976807
16 -0.00741072772658941687079492410817 -0.00741072772658940819717754422413 -0.00000000000000000867361737988404
17  0.18007029396551640920698389436438  0.18007029396551640920698389436438  0.00000000000000000000000000000000
18  0.13157654447972574884850871512754  0.13157654447972577660408433075645 -0.00000000000000002775557561562891
19  0.23623677929370121009178262738715  0.23623677929370123784735824301606 -0.00000000000000002775557561562891
20  0.09932199565529327422996885843531  0.09932199565529331586333228187868 -0.00000000000000004163336342344337
21 -0.05095804509442600910285037230096 -0.05095804509442600910285037230096  0.00000000000000000000000000000000
22 -0.08092279219264598977279234759408 -0.08092279219264594813942892415071 -0.00000000000000004163336342344337
23 -0.23319625415699421489001963436749 -0.23319625415699415937886840310966 -0.00000000000000005551115123125783
24  0.00495671069283426524165747650841  0.00495671069283432075280870776623 -0.00000000000000005551115123125783
25  0.23119641920851810579229379527533  0.23119641920851816130344502653315 -0.00000000000000005551115123125783
26  0.25282673483697731819930254459905  0.25282673483697731819930254459905  0.00000000000000000000000000000000
27  0.03160457726895595648164416502368  0.03160457726895599117611368455982 -0.00000000000000003469446951953614
28  0.01566407883863546804392719025145  0.01566407883863554437176013323096 -0.00000000000000007632783294297951
29 -0.15181719995420131508190308977646 -0.15181719995420125957075185851863 -0.00000000000000005551115123125783
30 -0.18723656696915602637432129995432 -0.18723656696915602637432129995432  0.00000000000000000000000000000000
31 -0.07811486111860536929452081267300 -0.07811486111860532766115738922963 -0.00000000000000004163336342344337
32 -0.20444686349359716959206423325668 -0.20444686349359711408091300199885 -0.00000000000000005551115123125783
33 -0.24196515292630801918782879056380 -0.24196515292630796367667755930597 -0.00000000000000005551115123125783
34 -0.14324766151539661263036862237641 -0.14324766151539658487479300674750 -0.00000000000000002775557561562891
35 -0.01668741793313034682544326869902 -0.01668741793313028784484508548758 -0.00000000000000005898059818321144
36 -0.20155891969265707364122874878376 -0.20155891969265701813007751752593 -0.00000000000000005551115123125783
37 -0.33901998761756196865135848383943 -0.33901998761756191314020725258160 -0.00000000000000005551115123125783
38 -0.25610064767786538952876185248897 -0.25610064767786527850645938997332 -0.00000000000000011102230246251565
39 -0.00627059309831806688251276682422 -0.00627059309831808509710926458069  0.00000000000000001821459649775647
```

and the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import talib
np.random.seed(999)
period = 12
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000))

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 10000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10000)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.32f' % x)


def manual_sma(prices, n):
    prices = prices.astype(np.double)
    ma = np.zeros_like(prices)
    ma[:n] = np.nan

    for i in range(n-1, len(prices)):
        ma[i] = np.nanmean(prices[i-n+1:i+1])
    return pd.Series(ma)


my_sma = manual_sma(ts, period)
pandas_sma = ts.rolling(period, min_periods=period).mean()
talib_sma = talib.SMA(ts, timeperiod=period)

df = pd.concat((talib_sma, my_sma), axis=1)
df.columns = ['talib', 'mine']
df['errors'] = df['talib'] - df['mine']
print(df.iloc[:40])
```

Comment: Since the Python code is ultimately executed using the same machine instructions as the C code, it is possible.

Comment: And if you use CPython, it even uses the same mathematical functions.